# WPF slider behaving like combobox

Tags: wpf, binding, slider

I need a control where user can pick only one option. Combobox is fine, radiobuttons are ok, but for some purpose I think about another crazy, but interesting solution.

There should be a slider control on a window and three possible positions of this sliding thing. I know this can be easily accomplished by setting slider's `Minimum` and `Maximum` plus `TickFrequency` and `IsSnapToTickEnabled` properties.

Now, is there a way how to add labels on left/right edge and center of slider showing user options within the slider? Or is it neccessary place labels/textblock below?

Last, though the most important thing is, how to associate integer slider positions with string options? I thought about switch, but this is wpf - there is "more wpf" solution, isn't it?

Just drag slider's rider to it's position and by binding set class string property to appropriate value.

Comment: Your idea might no be so crazy after all. Windows Phone 7 check boxes (sort of dual-valued controls) look and animate like small sliders.

Comment: Oh, it seems, I'm not only madman now :D You pleased me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every control within WPF can have its visuals completely modified to suit your needs. This was/is the beauty of WPF over WinForms.

Can your slider have a `TextBlock` within it? Absolutely. Style as you desire and be on your way. A great article can be found via MSDN Magazine which outlines the approach to [customizing WPF controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx).

With regard to the integer values, use an [IVauleConverter](http://www.wiredprairie.us/journal/2006/05/ivalueconverter_and_wpf.html) to translate the values to whatever you prefer.

Comment: Ok, IValueConverter could't be a problem. What about TextBlock within slider? Do you have any sample please?

Comment: @Andrew Added link to article on MSDN Magazine which provides a great in depth article on customizing WPF controls. It talks about the _Slider_ control within the article as well.